# Irreducibility of $x^{3}-3(p+q)x^{2}+3(p^{2}+q^{2})x-(p^{3}+q^{3})$ for positive integers $p$ and $q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ and $q$ be positive integers. How can I show that the polynomial $x^{3}-3(p+q)x^{2}+3(p^{2}+q^{2})x-(p^{3}+q^{3})$ is irreducible over the integers?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The equation is

$$(x-p)^3+(x-q)^3=x^3.$$

Comment: But which irreducibility criterion applies in this case?

Comment: This should blind you.

Comment: A cubic is irreducible if it has no root. Having no root was already discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644503/integer-roots-to-cubic-equation-with-integer-coefficients).

Comment: I tried to prove the irreducibility of the Fermat equation over the integers using only Gauss´s Lemma on monic polynomials with integer coefficients: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338819565_Proving_Fermats_Last_Theorem_as_a_Mean_Value_Problem_Title_Proving_Fermats_Last_Theorem_as_a_Mean_Value_Problem_Author